# Locate xpath of an element visible only on hover

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, xml-file

I am doing automation on the following :-[image]

The comments you see`(<!---->)` , changes when I hover over the INFY(in green on the left)
[image]

(See one of the comment changes to <span class = "actions"...)

What I performing for this(via python and selenium):

```
try:
# wait 10 seconds before looking for element
    INFYSYMB = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div"))
                                                    
    )
except:
    # else quit'
    print("Not done")
    driver.quit()

action =  ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(INFYSYMB)
```

Which hovers over it. Now I would like to click on the B. For it I need to inspect its  xpath or id or some information to store that element to perform click() action on it.

But if I move my mouse, it reverts back to `<!---->`. So how do I copy its xpath?

Comment: It  seems unclear to me what you're trying to do. You should be able to click a button without worrying about hover state. Or, are you wanting to get the text  of the hover element?

Comment: In the first image you see there is no buy button (one with Blue colored "B" in second).I want to be able to access this button (which becomes available when I hover over infy stock)

Comment: Can you use the console to trigger the mouseover state of that element?

Comment: thanks that worked awsomely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I understood, and I had similar problem sometimes. So in this case I make a screenshoot and I take the xpath. Advice you need to use xpath simpler, use descendant,...
Later I think you will have a new problem because this element only it's activated when the mouse is on the button, so you will need to use the library Actions (
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/python-selenium-all-mouse-actions-using-actionchains-197530cf75df) to move it